# Why am I able to kill my guide?

Tags: terraria-console

So in terraria for the Xbox One NPC's come to houses you've built, well when I hit my guide he takes damage! This doesn't happen with any other NPC in the game! Why does this happen? Or how can I stop this? I wasn't able to do it when I first got the game! (It happens with EVERY weapon).  The guide usually respawns within 1 in-game day.
Here's some other info as well

- PvP is off
- playing on my world; singleplayer
- Not using cheats or hacks

Comment: don`t equip  dolls . . . just keep it in some box for later use.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena Oh that's why! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You have the [Guide Voodoo Doll](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide_Voodoo_Doll) equipped

Equipping the Guide Voodoo Doll in one of your accessory slots gives you the ability to damage the Guide with your attacks. This was originally intended by the developers as a joke item to allow players to "get revenge" on the Guide (who many experienced players found annoying early in the game's development as NPCs have a tendency to open doors at inopportune times, along with the Guide being largely useless to an experienced player before his crafting information feature was added).

However, it was later given more importance, as the item is used to unlock Hardmode once you're ready. To enter hardmode in a world...

> ...drop the Guide Voodoo Doll into the lava in the Underworld, then defeat the boss that spawns. The Guide must be alive when you do this in order for the boss to spawn.